# VSTS get the user's group from a release

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, release

I'm doing a powershell script that is going to run within a release, I want to know how I can get the group from the user that is logged (from release)

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to solve here, not what you think will solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to get the user's group from a release process?

Based on my test, we can get the groups of a specific user with the tool **TFSSecurity.exe**. See [/im: Display information about identities that compose direct membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#im-display-information-about-identities-that-compose-direct-membership) for details.

You can run below PowerShell script to get the user's group:

```
Set-Alias TFSSecurity "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TFSSecurity.exe"

TFSSecurity /im /collection:https://instance.visualstudio.com n:"instance@hotmail.com"
```

I tested the script on TFS and it works as expected. But doesn't work on VSTS.

However it works when run it locally on any machine which sign in the VSTS.

[image]